# Improving one class in a pre-trained tensorflow object detection api model

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection-api, tensorflow-model-garden, resuming-training

I was trying to improve the phone mobile class in the pre-trained tf object detection API model (`efficientdet_d0_coco17_tpu-32`).

I have collected training data and created `tfrecords` where the `label_map.pbtext` is as the following:

```
item {
 id: 77
 name: 'mobile'
}
```

and updated the `pipeline.config` as the following:

```
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "checkpoint/ckpt-0" (of the pretrained model)
  fine_tune_checkpoint_version: V2
  fine_tune_checkpoint_type: "detection"
```

after training when I am trying to inference the new model, I am always getting **1** as `detection_classes`.

any idea what I am doing wrong? or continues learning is not possible here?

Comment: what's for num_classes in your pipeline.config ?

Comment: num_classes: 90

Comment: I'm not sure about this.. but maybe label_map should contain all the classes and not just the one you want to expand?

Comment: I will try, but then in the current case, I should get 77 as `detection_classes`